# Image getting stretched when displayed in rounded imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my RoundedImageView class that extends ImageView:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }
    Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
   // roundBitmap= ImageUtils.setCircularInnerGlow(roundBitmap, 0xFFBAB399, 4, 1);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;


    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


            return output;
}
```

And my xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.example.scaletypedemo.RoundedImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/a"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

         <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/a" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, the problem is, if I use ImageView the image displayed is not getting stretched but if I use the same image and display it in RoundedImageView and keeping all the properties same; the image is getting stretched as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Please help preventing the stretching of the image displayed in RoundedImageView...........I am badly stuck at this point.

Edit: After applying Zhenghong's solution, it resolved the stretching issue but then it is not showing the complete round.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Will it b helpful if you put ur roundImageView inside a layout and give ur layout as width and height as 100

<LinearLayout
   width=100
   height=100.....>
   <RoundedImageView
       width=wrap
       height=wrap.../>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: nopes......it still getting stretched!!!!!!

Comment: sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);  

You created a bitmap with same width and height. This is the reason why the image is stretched.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should resize your bitmap by its width/height rate.

----EDITED----
This will be a more flexible way to do it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
    int radius = w < h ? w : h;

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, radius, w, h);
    // roundBitmap= ImageUtils.setCircularInnerGlow(roundBitmap, 0xFFBAB399,
    // 4, 1);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius, int w, int h) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float _w_rate = 1.0f * radius / bmp.getWidth();
        float _h_rate = 1.0f * radius / bmp.getHeight();
        float _rate = _w_rate < _h_rate ? _h_rate : _w_rate;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() * _rate), (int)(bmp.getHeight() * _rate), false);
    }
    else
        sbmp = bmp;

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(w / 2, h / 2, (w < h ? w : h) / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help; your suggestion did solve the stretching issue but now it is not showing complete round.......please see the edit in my question

Comment: are you suggesting me to add  canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        radius, paint);  ?

Comment: yaa i saw the edit and only thing changed is :  canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        radius, paint);       right?

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks now working fine but image is showing little shifted bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to create a transparent PNG for the border (a hollowed out circle in a square) and place it as the background of a view directly above, and with the same dimensions, of the `ImageView`.

Something like this:

[image: Round Image Border]

**EDIT:**

Seems white on white images are porblematic :) (trust me, there's an image there...)
So I uplaoded 2 more:

[image]
[image]

Comment: yeah I already tried that solution but in that alternative, the problem is that in my real project there is some background....so that border of the png will not look good there....

Comment: I see, then you can take the rounding logic you created for your `RoundedImageView` and create a `RoundedFrameLayout` or some other layout the implements it. In your XML put a regular `ImageView` in the newly created `RoundedFrameLayout`.